# How to programmatically set a string value in a JavaFX ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

Basically, here is what I need:

I have a JavaFX ComboBox, and it is set to Editable. Since it is editable, there is a little text field in there where someone can enter in a String. I want to use previously generated data to populate that little text field. How do I accomplish this?

```
    enterSchoolName.setSelectionModel((SingleSelectionModel<String>) FXCollections.observableArrayList(studentData.getSchoolName()));
```

This is all i have in the way of relevant code and an "attempt" at a solution.

Answer (score 12):

You can set the data items of a `ComboBox` in the constructor:

```
 ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList("text1", "text2", "text3");
 ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(data);
```

or later:

```
comboBox.setItems(data);
```

To select a data item, you can select the appropriate index in the `SelectionModel` or the item itself:

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
comboBox.getSelectionModel().select("text1");
```

It's also possible to set a value to the combobox editor, which is not contained in the underlying datamodel:

```
comboBox.setValue("textXXX");
```

Answer (score 3):

The "little text field" in a editable `ComboBox` is known as the `editor` of the `ComboBox`. And it's a normal `TextField` object. To access that object, you need to use the method `ComboBox#getEditor()`. This way you can use the methods of the `TextField` class. If I understand you correctly, all you want to do is set the text of that `TextField`.

This is done by doing `comboBox.getEditor().setText(text)` or `comboBox.setValue(text)`. Both of these methods will set the text of the ComboBox.

But there's a difference when you want to fetch that text. `ComboBox#getValue()` `ComboBox#getEditor()#getText()` doesn't necessarily return the same value.

Consider the following example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestComboBox extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        comboBox.setValue("Test");
        comboBox.getItems().addAll("Test", "Test2", "Test3");

        VBox content = new VBox(5);
        content.getChildren().add(comboBox);
        content.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        GridPane valueGrid = new GridPane();

        Label cbValue = new Label();
        cbValue.textProperty().bind(comboBox.valueProperty());
        Label cbText = new Label();
        cbText.textProperty().bind(comboBox.getEditor().textProperty());

        valueGrid.add(new Label("ComboBox value: "), 0, 0);
        valueGrid.add(new Label("ComboBox text: "), 0, 1);
        valueGrid.add(cbValue, 1, 0);
        valueGrid.add(cbText, 1, 1);

        content.getChildren().add(valueGrid);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(content));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

If you change the text in the `ComboBox` by chosing an alternative in the list, both `ComboBox#valueProperty()` and `ComboBox#getEditor#textProperty()` changes. But as you can see if you type something into the `ComboBox`, only the textProperty changes.

So use whichever method you want when you set the text of the `ComboBox`, but be aware of the difference when you want to retrieve that text.